# LoaderManager not work

Tags: android, cursor, android-loadermanager

I need to use in query two tables. That's why I created my own Loader. But  in my Activity onLoadFinished never called.
 Cursor loader:

```
public class MagazinesLoader  extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {
private Cursor mCursor;
private ContentObserver mObserver;

public MagazinesLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mObserver = new ForceLoadContentObserver();
}

/* Runs on the UI thread */
@Override
public void deliverResult(Cursor cursor) {
    if (isReset()) {
        // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    mCursor = cursor;

    if (isStarted()) {
        super.deliverResult(cursor);
    }

    if (oldCursor != null && oldCursor != cursor && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
        oldCursor.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Starts an asynchronous load of the contacts list data. When the result is ready the callbacks
 * will be called on the UI thread. If a previous load has been completed and is still valid
 * the result may be passed to the callbacks immediately.
 * <p/>
 * Must be called from the UI thread
 */
@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        deliverResult(mCursor);
    }
    if (takeContentChanged() || mCursor == null) {
        forceLoad();
    }
}

/**
 * Must be called from the UI thread
 */
@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {
    // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
    cancelLoad();
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    // Ensure the loader is stopped
    onStopLoading();

    if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed()) {
        mCursor.close();
    }
    mCursor = null;
}
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    MagazinesOpenHelper magazinesOpenHelper=new MagazinesOpenHelper(getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = magazinesOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    mCursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT m.id, m.name, m.cover FROM magazine m, users_magazines um " +
            "WHERE  m.id=um.magazine_id AND um.user_id= '" +new SessionManager(getContext()).getUserId()+"'", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        // Ensure the cursor window is filled
        mCursor.getCount();
        mCursor.registerContentObserver(mObserver);
    }

    return mCursor;
}
```

}

In  Activity I use LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks:

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (id == MagazineQuery.TOKEN) {
       new MagazinesLoader(this);
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
protected void addDataObservers() {
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            MagazinesContract.Magazine.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    if (loader.getId() == MagazineQuery.TOKEN) {
        mCursor = data;
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor has " + mCursor.getCount() + " items. Will now update collection view.");
        updateGridWithMagazines();
    }
}
```

But onLoadFinished never called. In MagazinesLoader I ovveride loadInBackground method so it must work. Please help me to find the reason.

Comment: `"I need to use in query two tables. That's why I created my own Loader"` no, you need a custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: You was right. All is working